# Location Based Service Running in Background Forever

Tags: android, gps

My App : I am developing location based service, It is for tracking salesperson . Scenario is person xyz Wants to track his sales person , He will set the time and distance interval for getting location updates and after that he will handover cellphone to sales person and App should continuously running and track GPS .

Problem : I have almost completed the project but I want to run this app FOREVER to track ,I am doing this by GPS , When I minimize the app after setting time and distance my app will close By android OS but When it will be in FOREGROUND it works perfectly.

Kindly please suggest me what is the possible solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to do your tracking in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and not in the Activity itself so the app does it even if the user is not interacting with it.

And then the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is what you are looking for. You can schedule a Intent to be called at certain times. So you can check if your service is still running and if not restart it to start tracking again.

Take a **Look at [UpdateService](https://github.com/n3utrino/enl-atitude/blob/master/app/src/ch/n3utrino/enlatitude/services/UpdateService.java) from this app**.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(UPDATE_ACTION);
 PendingIntent alarmManagerPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

 mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), //Start now
                10*60*1000, //every 10 minutes
                alarmManagerPendingIntent);
```

Comment: http://pastie.org/6192104 look at my code here..I have used service but i m not getting where exactly to use alarammanager .. i just tried to print message in onDestroy but this method is not running when Android OS is killing App

Comment: I don't see your service. It is just the activity. But you want all your updating work in your service. So you can run it even if the activity is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a service instead / in addition to your regular app. Services can run even when application is closed. You can't run service "forever", and besides you can always go and stop the service manually. For the service to survive longer it must be a foreground service -  more here: [Running a Service in the Foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground).

Comment: startForeground() is not running on button click where we shd use this exactly ??

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateLocationService.class);
    getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
}
```